# Question about condition number $k$ of a matrix over a finite field

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $\lambda_{max}$, and $\lambda_{min}$ denote the maximum and minimum values of the eigenvalues of a normal square matrix repectively- are there any explicit bounds to the eigenvalues of such a square matrix, given the matrix is over a finite field, ie all the values in the matrix are in $GF(p)$ ($GF$ is Galois Field), and p is prime. Is there anything we can say about the condition number $k$ for a normal matrix over $GF(p)$?

Comment: The eigenvalues of a matrix with entries in $\Bbb{Z}_p$ are in some extension field of $\Bbb{Z}_p$. I'm not aware of any way of comparing two such things and calling one larger than the other. So what do you mean by $\lambda_{max}$? What is *condition number $k$*? What is $I$?

Comment: For clarification, $\lambda_{max}$, and $\lambda_{min}$ are max, and min eigenvalues of the normal matrix under consideration, with $I$ denotes integers, and condition number $k$ defined as the $\lambda_{max}$$/$$\lambda_{min}$.

Comment: Better in the sense that now we know for sure that the algebra is done modulo $p$! I still don't know how you compare eigenvalues. Are you aware that we don't have an ordering compatible with arithmetic operations in $GF(p)$? The reason is that if we declare $0<1$, then we also probably want $1<2$, $2<3$ et cetera. Eventually we get $p-1<p$. But if we want transitivity, then we get $1<p$. But $p=0$, so we arrive at $1<0$, which looks bad. So once more: How are we supposed to make sense of $\lambda_{max}$ and $\lambda_{min}$?

Comment: Is there any practical need to define a condition number for  a matrix over a finite field? I mean, the most basic reason to study condition number is to measure the effect of roundoff errors in the entries of a matrix $A$ to the solution of an equation such as $Ax=b$, but over a finite field, there is no such thing as a roundoff error.

Comment: The context of this study of condition number in a solution to the equation $Ax = B$, over a finite field, for which we have an approximation algorithm, and we would like to say something qualitatively about the algorithm, in the context of a finite field. We know for random matrices there are results for the condition number, but in the case when we are looking at a solution to the equation $Ax = B$, and we get an expectation value of the solution $\vec{x}$ , in case of finite fields, is there anything the condition number gives insight to the expectation value of the solution $\vec{x}$

Comment: @user1551 Unless it's a field of such a size that the elements, when represented by integers in double precision, get truncated to nearest multiple of some power of $2$. [I admit I don't know how people actually store the elements of finite field].